# eslint Parse errors in imported module for images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I'm currently working with a React Project and I typically add images I use for components in this way:

```
import CartImage from '../../images/icon_cart.png';
```

All is well and the image loads up properly in my app. Unfortunately the are some linting errors and warnings that I get:

> Parse errors in imported module '../../images/icon_cart.png':
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:1) import/namespace
>
> Parse errors in imported module '../../images/icon_cart.png':
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:1) import/default
>
> Parse errors in imported module '../../images/icon_cart.png':
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:1) import/import/no-named-as-default
>
> Parse errors in imported module '../../images/icon_cart.png':
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:1) import/no-named-as-default-member

This happens to all files where I import an image. Below is my .eslintrc:

```
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:import/errors",
        "plugin:import/warnings"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "jquery": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "quotes": 0,
        "no-console": 1,
        "no-debugger": 1,
        "no-var": 1,
        "semi": [1, "always"],
        "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
        "eol-last": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-alert": 0,
        "no-lone-blocks": 0,
        "jsx-quotes": 1,
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "react/display-name": [ 1, {"ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
        "react/forbid-prop-types": [1, {"forbid": ["any"]}],
        "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
        "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
        "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
        "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
        "react/jsx-key": 1,
        "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
        "react/jsx-no-bind": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
        "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
        "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/no-danger": 1,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
        "react/no-set-state": 0,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
        "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
        "react/prop-types": 1,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
        "react/require-extension": "off",
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/sort-comp": 1,
        "react/wrap-multilines": "off"
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "paths": ["src"] 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried adding the following settings to my .eslintrc file:

```
  "import/ignore": [
    ".(png)"
  ]
```

The error for the images went away but now I keep getting errors for most of my javascript files similar to below:

> 1:8  No default export found in module  import/default

For example, all my files with this:

> import webpack from ‘webpack’;

Now gets the no default export found in module error.

Anything else wrong with my eslint configuration?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of an import that's giving the error.

Comment: It’s in my question at the start.

Comment: You said you solved that issue, but that now you get errors with the JavaScript files instead. Add an example of a failing JavaScript import.

Comment: Updated now with a sample import.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you should never import webpack into your modules. It's a build tool, not a module to be referenced inside your other modules. Try commenting out all instances of that and see if you still have errors.

Comment: Unfortunately that error shows up in my webpack.config.js when I run eslint.

Comment: So you're getting `1:8 No default export found in module import/default` inside webpack.config.js? You shouldn't need to import webpack into that file - see here for details on what you can include in the config file: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: I think it's not possible. If I don't import webpack then I'll be getting errors when I try to add plugins like: `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()`

By the way, I'm using webpack 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the parser ignore the folder that contains your images or gifs.
In my case I added to my eslintrc the following properties:

```
  ignorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/',
    'src/serviceWorker.ts',
    'template/src/serviceWorker.ts',
    'src/assets/statics/'
  ],
```